# When Hydra will be ready for production?

Tags: hydra

I understand that Hydra is a work in progress, but it already has a [POC](https://github.com/input-output-hk/hydra-poc) version. If there is no clear deadline, where can I find a development plan at least ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW We created a Github project to serve as our public roadmap: https://github.com/orgs/input-output-hk/projects/21

It does show individual features, in what releases they are planned to be included and roughly in what time frame we aim to be tackling them. The quarters in one of the views are only forecasts and any impact in velocity will change them - it's a research & development project after all!

Answer (score 3):

There is no official roadmap just yet, but we plan to publish it soon. However, don't expect definite deadlines on that, but rather a sequence of features with frequent & incremental releases. Research & development is an inaccurate art :) Where and in which form would you expect such a roadmap?

Comment: I think something like Cardano roadmap (https://roadmap.cardano.org/) would be useful. There could be a list of phases of development. As for where, it would be great to have it on cardano.org, probably it would also be something like public assurance.

Comment: Also it'd be great to have an infographic of sorts detailing what functions are possible with each iteration of Hydra along the approximate roadmap.